# Need to move the top red selector along with the bottom list scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I need to move the above shown red selector along with the bottom horizontal scrollview. Currently it is happening after the scrolling is finished.

Here is my code that I am using:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating1:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.x == 0) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
            self.selectMessageCatagoriesLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 41, [CommonUtils getFlexibleWidth:125], 3);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        }];
    }
    else if (scrollView.contentOffset.x == 375) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
            self.selectMessageCatagoriesLabel.frame = CGRectMake([CommonUtils getFlexibleWidth:125], 41, [CommonUtils getFlexibleWidth:125], 3);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        }];
    }
    else{
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
            self.selectMessageCatagoriesLabel.frame = CGRectMake([CommonUtils getFlexibleWidth:250], 41, [CommonUtils getFlexibleWidth:125], 3);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        }];
    }
}
```

Please check the screenshot for the reference

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scrollViewDidScroll` method from `UIScrollViewDelegate`, so you can move your code inside this method. You don't need to use animation in this method, because it called very frequently.